# Mouse not working

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have recently been asked to help fix a co-workers' laptop, which is running Windows 7 Home Premium, x64 edition, appears to be infected by malware. I think I've got the malware cleaned, but I can't get the mouse to work. I've tried both the touchpad—with the both the generic PS/2 driver, and the manufacture's driver—and an external USB mouse, both with the same problem.

In both cases, this error appears in the device manager:

> Windows cannot start this hardware device because its configuration
>   information (in the registry) is incomplete or damaged. (Code 19).

Does anyone know where the registry entries for this driver are located? Could I simply copy these entries from another computer?

**Update**: I deleted (after exporting, for backup) the entire **{4D36E96F-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}** (using [THIS](https://superuser.com/a/820635/239745) answer below) key and rebooted. Now, I'm getting another error: **This device cannot start (Code 10). I then exported the same key from another Windows 7 x64 computer, and imported it on this one, and got the same error (code 10). It seems there is, by default, one upper filter called *mouclass*. Could this be the culprit?

PS: I've decided to run **sfc /scannow** to see if that can somehow fix the issue. No issues were found.

**Update #2**: After undoing all of the changes I made to the registry, I found my problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! After re-importing the the registry key that I had backed-up before modifying anything, I found a strange upper class filter which wasn't present on another computer running Windows 7: klmouflt. Deleting this filter, while leaving the other filter (mouclass) intact seems to have done the trick (although a reboot was required).

I don't know what either of these filters are, but I guess mouclass is somehow important, while klmouflt is a problem causer for me. I suppose klmouflt might be malicious, since my google search showed several webpages with words like "Kaspersky", "Malware", and "Infected".

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes your problem happens because of a conflict between the hardware and a software program:

1. To solve this problem you must—as you said—delete the registry of
   that hardware with uninstall to the latest software. To make it
   right you must follow the steps at this link [How To Delete the
   UpperFilters and LowerFilters Registry Values](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/ht/upperfilters-lowerfilters.htm)
2. To know the registry key of your hardware follow this link [Device
   Class GUIDs for Most Common Types of Hardware](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/a/device-class-guid.htm) (remmber the
   mouse class code is `{4D36E96F-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` and its
   location at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class`. Note you will find at this page a link to device manager error codes.

Comment: I've deleted the entry, and apparently that fixed the error. Unfortunately, I've gotten another error as a result. See my edit.

Comment: OK lets start first by make a backup to your computer OS and registry before we make any thing

Comment: never never never copy these registry entries from another computer

Comment: If you made that rollback to the previous registry immediately